# How do I resolve attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x00400024 error code in Qtspim?

Tags: assembly, syntax-error, qtspim

I am working on a homework assignment that prompts the user for a temperature in Celsius, which is read as a floating point value using a trap handler service. The temperature will then be converted into Fahrenheit and printed out. This is what I have so far and I am unsure of how to fix this, I have tried using syscall 10 but haven't had any luck. There is also a syntax error at "nine: .float 9" that I'm unsure of.

```
main:
    .data
    inMsg: .asciiz "Enter Celsius: "
    outMsg: .asciiz "Fahrenheit: "
    nine: .float 9
    five: .float 5
    thirtytwo: .float 32

    .text

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, inMsg           ## Print inMsg
    syscall

    li $v0, 6               ## Ask for float input
    syscall
    mov.s $f1, $f0

    l.s $f2, nine
    mul.s $f1, $f1, $f2
    l.s $f2, five
    div.s $f1, $f1, $f2
    l.s $f2, thirtytwo
    add.s $f1, $f1, $f2

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, outMsg          ## Print outMsg
    syscall

    li $v0, 2
    mov.s $f12, $f1
    syscall

    exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Hopefully SPIM comes with a debugger that will let you stop at the point of failure to see what's wrong. (For example, it seems you put data at the start of your `main` function, which is probably not a great idea.) [Note also that since this is a homework assignment, you should cite all outside assistance you received to avoid academic dishonesty.]

Comment: It looks like you have put your `main:` on your data, whereas it belongs on your code.  Move the `main:` to after the `.text` directive and it will probably be better.